# undefined local variable or method `zip_codes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

After trying to change the search to pull locations from the zip code and not the location_id the results return empty.

I had the code previously working when I used location ids. Does someone know how I can get it to work with the zip codes? I have a `zip_code` column in the Users table and `zipcode` column in the Locations table.

The location_id being used a auto increment from each row in the Locations table.

Current code:

```
def index
    if location = Location.find_by_zipcode(params[:search])
        latitude  = location.latitude * Math::PI / 180 
        longitude = location.longitude * Math::PI / 180 

        zip_codes = Location.search_for_ids( 
          :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
          :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..400_000.0}, 
          :order => 'geodist ASC',
          :per_page => 1_000
        ) 
        @users = User.where(:zip_code => zip_codes)
```

Code that works with location_id:

```
  def index
    if location = Location.find_by_zipcode(params[:search])
        latitude  = location.latitude * Math::PI / 180 
        longitude = location.longitude * Math::PI / 180 

        location_ids = Location.search_for_ids( 
          :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
          :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..400_000.0}, 
          :order => 'geodist ASC',
          :per_page => 1_000
        ) 
        @users = User.where(:location_id => location_ids)
```

Tables

```
Location:
      t.string :zipcode
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude


      User:
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :zip_code
      t.string :location_id
      t.string :time_zone
      t.string :birthday
      t.string :name
      t.string :username
```

The location id was a auto increment.

Comment: The error is in `@users = User.where(:zip_code => zip_codes)`. What is supposed to be zip_codes there?

Comment: I'm a little but confused; is that `index` method in a controller? Ultimately, the error is indicating that you do not have a method or variable called `zip_codes` anything within the accessible scope of whatever class contains this code. There is not enough information to tell you why it worked one way and not the other. Ultimately, where is that `zip_codes` entity coming from, or supposed to be coming from?

Comment: @eKek0 If I change it to `zip_codes = Location.search_for_ids` and `         @users = User.where(:zip_code => zip_codes)` it will return no users. Currently I am Searching for Object Ids `Article.search_for_ids 'pancakes'` And instead I am trying to search by the `zip_code`

Comment: @Teeg the index method is inside the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Side Note: The original version of this answer was posted before we determined that [thinking-sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/) was being used, so it is important to note that I have never used this gem / library, and can only offer my best estimated guess based on the documentation.*

The error message is saying you don't have a method or variable called `zip_codes`, which from what we can see in the code, is correct (it is most definitely not defined anywhere).

If I am correct that thinking-sphinx returns an array of Active Record objects (or something similar), then I believe you should be able to use most of this code (using the [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method below).

Rather than using the `search_for_ids` method, which I believe *only* returns a collection of database row ids, we'll use the normal `search` method. As my understanding goes, what is returned from the `search` method is a collection of fully populated active record objects. I believe your location search will look like this:

```
locations = Location.search
      :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
      :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..400_000.0}, 
      :order => 'geodist ASC',
      :per_page => 1_000
```

You should be safe, at that point, to extract only the `zipcode` fields from that collection, like so:

```
User.where(zip_code: locations.pluck(:zipcode))
```

If the `pluck` method does not exist for that collection, you may need to try the same procedure with the `map` method instead:

```
locations.map(&:zipcode)
```

Or a more explicit version:

```
locations.map{|location| location.zipcode}
```

The reason why your attempt to do `.where(:zip_code => zip_codes)` after renaming the variable is because (most likely) your `zip_codes` (previously named `location_zips`) is an array of objects, not a collection of zipcodes as you expected. Admittedly, this is an assumption because I do not know what this `search_by_zipcode` method does, but this seems like a reasonable explanation based on the behaviour you described.

Comment: If I add this to the original working code I get `uninitialized constant SearchesController::Users`. The search ids was pulled from the docs `If you would like just the primary key values returned, instead of instances of ActiveRecord objects, you can use all the same search options in a call to search_for_ids instead.`

Comment: @CorneliusWilson Can you show me what docs you're talking about? I have never heard of this `search_for_ids` method; I assumed it was something of your own creation. Also, yes I made a typo. Users = User.

Comment: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html under `Search for Object IDs` Perhaps I should change the location_zips to a search call so the Location objects are returned?

Comment: @CorneliusWilson Oooook, so you're using the thinking-sphinx gem. I guess you didn't realize it, but that is an absolutely crucial piece of information that should be included in questions. If we don't know what library(ies) you're using, we can't properly answer the question, and we make incorrect assumptions (as what has happened here). I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you. The pluck method did not exist so I used the map. You did a excellent job at explaining what you did so that I could understand and learn from it. Thanks for taking the time out of your day to assist me. My apologizes for making this harder than it should, I thought I noted the gem but I never did. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @CorneliusWilson No problem, glad we figured it out. And don't worry, I figured it just an accidental omission. Besides, now that I know about that gem, I may make use of it in the future. I am somewhat surprised though that `pluck` didn't exist, but I guess `search` probably returns a plain 'ol array, instead of an active record collection. Either way, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) as follows:

```
@users = User.joins(
                 'inner join locations on users.zip_code = locations.zipcode'
              ).where('locations.zipcode = ?', params[:zipcode])
```

Also I'm assuming you want `params[:zipcode]` in your `where` method not `zip_codes` which does not seem to be defined.

Comment: This returns only user with the specific zip code. `@users = User.where(:location_id => location_ids)` allows the geo search to pull all users within specific distance. The problem I have is that instead of matching the location id from the Users & Location table I would like to match the zip codes. Currently I have to manually enter in the `location_id` on the Users table after a user registers. This is why I am trying to change it so that the search requires the zip code and not a id.